# Superpower show with a guy who could duplicate himself

Tags: story-identification, tv

I watched a television show when I was in high school so the show was running between 2006~2009, so was probably released around 2004~2006, maybe earlier.
It was about ordinary people who got superpower after some freaky accident.
One of them got the power to duplicate himself, send his clone somewhere to do a mission.

The clone would act exactly as the guy would originally act, and have all of his memories, and when he is finished with his task, he could go back and reconnect with the main guy, and that guy would immediately get all of the memories of the clone and know exactly what he did and how he acted.

Comment: Live action? Animated? Could the guy create multiple clones or only one? Any of [the clones from _Heroes_](https://heroeswiki.com/Cloning) ring a bell? Where was this aired (if you're willing to share), did it seem to be a Japanes/European/wherever production?

Comment: It was live action, there was one clone but I don't remember that they said anything about not being able to create more. I don't know what network it was since it was bought and aired on a local tv channel. The show was American. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Are you sure that everyone was ordinary in the series. In the tv-series Smallville for example, that ran 2001-2011, one of the characters has the power to create and reabsorb duplicates of himself.

Comment: It was definitely not Smallville, I tried to watch it and gave up after 3 episodes. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It could be [The 4400](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_4400)

From wikipedia:

> The 4400 (pronounced "the forty-four hundred") is a science fiction television series produced by CBS Paramount Network Television in association with BSkyB, Renegade 83, and American Zoetrope for USA Network.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_4400) The show was created and written by Scott Peters and René Echevarria, and it starred Joel Gretsch and Jacqueline McKenzie. The series ran for four seasons from 2004 until its cancellation in 2007.
>
> In the pilot episode, an enormous ball of light deposits a group of exactly 4400 people in the Cascade Range foothills near Mount Rainier, Washington. Each of the 4400 had disappeared in a beam of white light at various times starting in 1946. None of the 4400 have aged from the time of their disappearance. Confused and disoriented, they remember nothing between the time of their disappearance and their return.

It was a show that run from 2004-2007 and was about ordinary humans that got abducted by a white light, and when they returned they had superpowers.
One of the characters Jed Garrity got the power to create duplicates. It was only revealed in the final episode though.

Comment: I watched it also, amazing show, but not the one I'm trying to remember.

Answer (score 3):

Partial match: *Misfits* (2009).

It's a bit off your time frame, as it got released in 2009 and the duplicating guy, Rudy, only arrived in season 3, but from what I remember, the "freaky accident gives superpowers" and "clone merges after the fact" kind of match. However, Rudy's more of a "split personality" so to say, with one duplicate being a shy one, and the other kind of an as... not a very nice guy.

> And there's a third one who's really a meanie.

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1548850/):

> Nathan, Kelly, Simon, Alisha and Curtis were expecting their community service to be boring. However after a freak thunderstorm they discover that it is anything but dull. Bestowed with strange powers, the five very different teens realize they have a lot more to worry about than just picking up litter, especially as they discover that they are not the only ones who have been given strange powers. Secrets will be revealed, feelings brought to the surface and relationships formed and broken. But hey, its only 12 weeks of community service; what's the worst that could happen?

Warning, not always safe for work:

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I watched Misfits at the time but it's not the one.